# VS Code remote container development, Self signed error

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using VS code behind a proxy, when I launch my application in vscode using remote-container: Open Folder in Container, I get the following error

Last 5 lines from console are as follows

```
Installing VS Code Server for commit 9ff8ae037e8e6109d65e4b5e3eb3dc60cc187e21

Run: docker exec 4fb52a0c330728418847e744137e17794569847c060c4b73d825bf7a705c37c7 mkdir -p /root/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/9ff8ae037e8e6109d65e4b5e3eb3dc60cc187e21_1561144150809

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I have my proxy setting in WINDOWS, WSL environments

I have also set the http.proxy and proxyStrictSSL=false in the workspace setting

My .devcontainer.json has the following

```
    {
        "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
        "service": "my-service",
        "workspaceFolder": "/src",
        "extensions": [],
        "settings": {
            "http.proxy": "http://host.docker.internal:8888",
            "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
        }
    }
```

Please note Installing VSCode server works fine in WSL environment.

Comment: Added certificate to my docker container verified the cert installation, but no progress yet

Comment: Was able to get the log
[exthost] [trace] ExtHostCommands#registerCommand remote-containers.revealLogTerminal

[2019-06-25 07:59:09.704] [exthost] [trace] ExtHostCommands#$executeContributedCommand remote-containers.revealLogTerminal

[2019-06-25 07:59:10.684] [exthost] [error] ProxyResolver#getCertificates (intermediate value) is not a function

[2019-06-25 07:59:10.686] [exthost] [trace] ProxyResolver#resolveProxy settings https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:e80dd4f217db6e230d311a87fdf4276f740f6445/server-linux-x64/insider PROXY localhost:8888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to code-insider to code stable fixed it.

Seems to be an issue with code-insider and understandable that its could be unstable